# is_valid() function returning false based in the traceback from a IntergerField in forms

Tags: python, django

is_valid() function returning false based in the traceback from a IntergerField in forms. I am probably missing out on something in the is_valid() line of code. Any input is appreciated.

traceback

```
[27/Apr/2020 02:23:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10413
5
<bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <IdForm bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(id)>>
<tr><th><label for="id_id">Song ID:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input type="text" name="id" required id="id_id"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_id">Song ID:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input type="text" name="id" required id="id_id"></td></tr>
<bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <IdForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(id)>>
[27/Apr/2020 02:23:09] "POST /playlist/add/5/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4406
```

forms.py

```
class IdForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.CharField(label='Song ID', required=True)
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'playlist_add' P_id=p.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="{{request.post.id}}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {%for field in form%}
        {{field.errors}}
        {{field}}
        {%endfor%}
        <button type="submit">Add Song</button>
      </form>
```

views.py

```
class PlaylistAddFormFunction(View):
    form_class = IdForm #determine fields
    template = 'homepage_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        print('soo')
        return render(request, self.template, {'form':form})

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request, P_id):
        print(P_id)
        form = IdForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('xoo')
            id = form.cleaned_data['id']
            song = Song.objects.get(id=id)
            playlist, created = Playlist.objects.get_or_create(id=P_id)
            playlist.song.add(song)
            return redirect('home')

        else:
            print(form)
            form = self.form_class(None)
            print(form.is_valid)
            return render(request, self.template, {'form':form})
```

Comment: What is  value of `request.POST`? Does it have the `id` field?

Comment: what is `form.errors` ?

Comment: @AmanGarg, not sure what you are referring to but my form only has one field 'id' and printing request.POST gives <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['5lgrGZ5qk2nvQ30LVjrQ5KIoG1GC3lHm7CLWLQ46cVT63hNf8cyHhOlArdT2Jy91']}>.

Comment: @ansuman, my form is not printing any errors on the template page when i enter the id numbers, but the data is not valid based on the traceback.

Comment: i meant in your view `def post(self, request, P_id)`. in the else part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I created 2 forms on a single template. Django got the 2 forms mixed up and rendered the submit button from the other form to the the current form. Thus, I am running the wrong function upon activating the POST method.